# Getting the mean value of multiple frames

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get the mean value of a let's 10 frames in Opencv. 
I didn't find anything that could be usefull.

does anybody how this works?
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the definition of a *value of a frame*?  Can a frame be reduced to a single value?

Comment: Echoing Thomas, what are you defining as a _value_ of the frame? Do you want to average the pixels of ten frames? Are you extracting a single value (such as average luminance) from each frame and want to average those?

Comment: with value of frame I mean the average of the pixels of ten frames

Comment: Lets say each "frame" has 10 pixels. Do you want to compute the mean value of all 100 pixels (from 10 frames with 10 pixels each) or the mean of the 10 mean values?